# remove background of RGB image (3D array) based on another array (boolean mask)

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I'm stuck on what should be fairly straight forward, but other opened questions don't see to address exactly the same issue i'm having.

I'm trying to crop an image based on boolean mask. I can do this with:

```
# crop image based on segmentation mask
def get_segment_crop(img,tol=0, mask=None):
    for i in range(mask.shape[2]):  
        crops = []
        if mask is None:
            mask = img > tol
        for i in range(mask.shape[2]):
            crops.append(img[np.ix_(mask[:,:,i].any(1), mask[:,:,i].any(0))])
        return crops
```

(This function inputs RGB image (w, h, c) and `True`/`False` mask of shape (w, h, n) and crops a bounding box around each segmentation mask).
But then I want to try to remove the background (ie. set everything that isn't `True` to `0`) around each segmentation mask of the cropped outputs (the mask segmentations are shapes -- not perfect rectangles). I thought that removing the background first then cropping could work, but i'm stuck on the removing the background part because my image has 3 channels.

Here's a working example and what i've tried so far with the issues i'm facing embedded as comments.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = misc.face()
img = np.array(file)

#create random masks
tf_mask = np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 2), False)
tf_mask[500:600,500:600,0] = True
tf_mask[500:650, 550:700, 0] = True
tf_mask[100:200, 100:200, 1] = True
tf_mask[200:300, 100:150, 1] = True
# np.where(tf_mask[:,:,0])[0] #sanity check True values were inputed

# Trying to set all values in img where masks=False to 0. Problem: it saves over original img array so the next mask doesn't display region of interest from original image
for i in range(tf_mask.shape[2]):
    img[tf_mask[:,:,i]==False] = 0
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

# issue with this: image is 3 channels so need to iterate over all channels but how to then merge back?
for i in range(tf_mask.shape[2]):
    for j in range(3):
        new_img = np.where(tf_mask[:,:, i]==False, 0, img[:,:,j])
        plt.imshow(new_img)
        plt.show()
```

Thanks for ideas to get around this or if there's a neater way to do this.

Comment: Seems like your mask should be 2d - `(w,h)` with the same w,h dimension of the image. If you can make the mask conform to that you should be able to multiply the mask and the image - the mask will broadcast to all three channels. `mask[:,:,None] * img`

Comment: the masks themselves are 2D of size (w,h) but because my img is segmented into multiple masks (the image has many objects that are being detected), I end up with an array of size (w,h,n) where n = number of detected objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple masks in a single 3d array where the first two dimensions are the same as the image and the individual masks are *stacked* in the third dimension, first collapse the mask(s) along the third dimension then multiply it with the image.

Assuming you want to keep a *pixel* if it is True in any the masks:

```
mask = np.any(mask,axis=-1)
masked = mask[:,:,None] * img
```

---

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = np.ones((3,3,3))
b = rng.integers(0,1,(3,3,2),endpoint=True,dtype=bool)

>>> a
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
>>> b
array([[[ True, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[False,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True,  True]]])
>>> b[0,0,:]
array([ True, False])
>>> b[0,1,:]
array([False,  True])
>>> b[0,2,:]
array([False, False])
>>> b = np.any(b,axis=-1)
>>> b[0,0]
True
>>> b[0,1]
True
>>> b[0,2]
False
>>> a * b[:,:,None]
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: there's still the issue of img being 3D tho (`operands could not be broadcast together with shape (w, h) (w, h, 3)`)

Comment: i tried `msk = np.all(tf_mask, axis=-1)
print(msk.shape)
masked = msk[:,:,None] * img
plt.imshow(masked)
plt.show()` but the masks are not appearing (returns a full black rectangle)

Comment: Sorry, see edit - you need to add the third dimension to the 2d mask.

Comment: i tried that, but it returns a completely black image. i think there is a problem with the collapsing in the 3rd dim (`np.all(tf_mask, axis=-1)` line)

Comment: Assuming mask[:,:,0] is a 2d boolean array that identifies an object, and mask[:,:,1] identifies a different object. Probably need to use `np.any` - see edit

Comment: indeed, my bad, read as `all`. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to create the mask first?

If you are manually typing in the mask range values, just use those to index your array:

img = img[500:600,500:600,:]

If you insist on masks, you can just multiply your mask by your img, but make sure your mask and img have the same shape.

img = img * mask. You'll have your values where mask == True and 0's where mask == False

Comment: I am not, this is just for a mwe. I am running a mask rcnn model and extracting the masks from the model's outputed segmentations

Comment: I just edited my first comment:If you insist on masks, you can just multiply your mask by your img, but make sure your mask and img have the same shape.

img = img * mask. You'll have your values where mask == True and 0's where mask == False